# Keep tables in sync between databases on the same server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I've got a database with a table that is updated whose updates I need to push to an archive database so the two tables are identical.

Do I use replication? What is the most efficient choice given I have roughly 14,000 rows (increases daily to become roughly 30,000 rows every two months or so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with transactional replication. Your other options would be to do this in code with a synchronous trigger or asynchronously via service broker, which IMHO, is a much bigger pain to set up than replication.

Comment: That won't tie down the same server? None of what I read talks about how to set that up.

Comment: Tie down the server how? Any solution is going to take server resources since both DBs are on the same box. If it satisfies your business requirements, you can schedule the transactional replication push to occur once per day during off hours.

Comment: That sounds promising. Is that hard to set up?

Comment: @Caveatrob: Not at all. Google "sql server 2005 set up transactional replication" and you'll find several how-to articles.